# histogram of event data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following data:

```
    start_time               end_time         duration       ic_total             mc_total
0   2022-01-01 10:00:00 2022-01-01 19:00:00    9.0             0.0            1.7780003947160878
1   2022-01-02 00:00:00 2022-01-02 10:00:00    10.0            0.0                  0.0
2   2022-01-02 17:00:00 2022-01-03 02:00:00    9.0      0.7620001691640255    1.7780003947160594
3   2022-01-03 02:00:00 2022-01-04 12:00:00    34.0     3.810000845820184     4.31800095859623
4   2022-01-07 21:00:00 2022-01-08 06:00:00    9.0      10.287002283714486    1.016000225552034
5   2022-01-16 05:00:00 2022-01-16 20:00:00    15.0            0.0                  0.0
6   2022-01-19 04:00:00 2022-01-19 17:00:00    13.0     2.286000507492133     0.5926667982386957
7   2022-01-21 14:00:00 2022-01-22 00:00:00    10.0     1.7780003947160736          0.0
8   2022-01-27 02:00:00 2022-01-27 16:00:00    14.0     14.986003326892735     9.588502128647471
```

in a dataframe.

How can I produce a plot with bars whose width are defined by the duration column, and height by the ic_total value?, and whos position on the x axis is defined by the start and end time?

Thanks to the answer from [Riley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71798066/histogram-of-event-data/71798306#71798306), I can now plot the data as desired, but have run into a further problem!
I have similar data in seperate dataframes, and want to plot them on the same plot. i have the following code:

```
_, ax = plt.subplots(sharex=False)

sc.Stairs(bdf, "start_time", "end_time", "ic_total").plot(ax,label='Bresser\open')
sc.Stairs(frdf, "start_time", "end_time", "ic_total").plot(ax, label='FR Gauge')
sc.Stairs(hpdf, "start_time", "end_time", "ic_total").plot(ax, label='Highpoint')
```

If I run the code it generates the plot bottom right in screenshot.(figure 4). Running each line individually generates the staircase plot successfully (figures 1-3).
[image]
I've tried sharex=False with no joy. I'm guessing that there is some sort of conflict wityh the x axis, is it possible toi plot each line with it's own axis and will this solve the issue?

Second edit:

on further investigation it seems that the original answer doesn't work after all. The bars should have a width defined by the 'duration' column, which is the time in hours between 'start_time' and 'end_time', is this more of a histogram question?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a step function plot to me, for which you can use [`staircase`](https://staircase.dev), which operates as part of the pandas ecosystem.

Assuming your dataframe is called `df` the following will produce a plot with little effort

```
import staircase as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

_, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,4))
sc.Stairs(df, "start_time", "end_time", "ic_total").plot(ax)
```

[image]

**note:** I am the creator of staircase. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: Superb! thankyou.
As a further question, how would I then add more lines to that plot?
data is in the same format, just different columns or dataframes

Comment: you have the `ax` object which is a matplotlib axes so you can manipulate the chart using that. If you wanted to add another step function then you just pass it to the plot function again. You can include all the typical matplotlib keyword arguments in the plot function too, eg linewidth=3, color=”red”, label="line1” etc

Comment: Sorry @riley, i had to 'un-accept' your answer, as it doesn't seem to work. the width of the bars does not correspond to the duration column., and as i have said in my edit, it falls over when you try and plot another dataframe onto the figure.

Comment: No worries.  Have you got an example of where the bar width does not correpond to duration?

Comment: @mattcooper check your date data is `pandas.Timestamp` and not strings.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this problem, my answer, detailing the method used is here.

[Matt Cooper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71817820/plotting-events-on-a-line-graph)